# Can connect to a MAMP setup localhost with Mac, but PC doesn't connect

Tags: macos, mamp

I have MAMP on my Mac, and I can access my locally hosted sites like so

```
http://localhost:8888/wordpress/
```

When I switch to my PC on the same network, I can enter `localhost` but it will not connect to my MAMP connection. I swear I have done this before. They are both on the same network.

Do I need to enable anything special on MAMP to get my PC to connect to localhost ?

I've also tried entering the IP address of the Mac into my browser's address bar to no avail.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I switch to my PC on the same
>   network, I can enter localhost but it
>   will not connect to my MAMP connection

Right. Because every computer thinks that ***its*** name is localhost. From another machine, you'd want to use something like http://*ip.add.re.ss*:8888/wordpress/ where ip.add.re.ss is the IP address of your Mac.

Your next issue is likely going to be that the site looks differently from the PC than when browsing from the Mac. Log into WordPress and make sure that the URL values at the Settings -> General page are a DNS resolvable name or IP address -- **not** "localhost."

Comment: Perfect answer!